# JSON::ParserError: 783: unexpected token at '--- in Paper-trail gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to setup a logger activities uses paper-trail gem with ability to export data to CSV. To do so I'm using below code:

```
CSV.open(file_path, 'w', col_sep: ';', write_headers: true, headers: LOG_HEADERS, encoding: 'UTF-8') do |csv|
  PaperTrail::Version.all.each do |version|
    csv << [version.whodunnit,
            version.event,
            JSON.parse(version.object_changes),
            version.created_at]
  end
end
```

I'm getting an error: `JSON::ParserError: 783: unexpected token at '---`

So the error is related with this line `JSON.parse(version.object_changes)` but I don't know why. The JSON under the hood is like below:

```
[46] pry(main)> PaperTrail::Version.last.object_changes
  PaperTrail::Version Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "versions".* FROM "versions" ORDER BY "versions"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> "---\nencrypted_password:\n- \"$2a$11$ItAi513BtaFkAqJSIfECYuiaK7ngjY3dLQ1Fv.WLKz9TiBARjqu5e\"\n- \"$2a$11$nmB.btqqTKdjvDCGhD9E1.eyA6c/6de5PMVqBjqcwal4CPowFqsce\"\nname:\n- test name\n- New - Mathias\nupdated_at:\n- 2020-08-31 21:28:45.871150000 Z\n- 2020-08-31 21:30:02.117589000 Z\n"
```

I'm using Rails 6 and Ruby 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the data was stored in yaml format instead of json, maybe you can try doing this:

```
YAML.load(version.object_changes)
```

That'll generate a hash with all the changes for that particular version.